# convert row output to column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

[image]

```
with cte1 as 
(
select count(*) as count_emp from emp; 
),
 cte2 as 
(
select count(*)  as count_dept from dept; 
),
 cte3 as 
(
select count(*)  as count_hr  from hr; 
)
select count_emp,count_dept,count_hr from cte1,cte2,cte3;
```

**I want output in one column with three rows. 
for more details see image .**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `union all`:

```
select count_emp from cte1
union all
select count_dept from cte2
union all
select count_hr from cte3;
```

Do note that the results are not guaranteed to be in any particular order.  I would highly advise you to label the rows:

```
select 'emp', count_emp as cnt from cte1
union all
select 'dept', count_dept from cte2
union all
select 'hr', count_hr from cte3;
```